# How to join 2 tables with select and count in single query

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I need to join 2 tables (Person and PersonLine). The result should contain `id` and `name` column from Person table and count of `personlineid` column from PersonLine Table for each `id`. But sql query returns count of all `personlineid`. Can anyone help to form the sql.

Person:

```
ID          NAME            AGE
100         John            25
101         James           30
102         Janet           35
```

PersonLine:

```
ID          NAME            PERSONLINEID
100         John            1
100         John            2
100         John            3
101         James           1
101         James           2
102         Janet           1
```

SQL:

```
SELECT P.ID, CNT.COUNT_PERSONLINE, P.NAME 
    FROM PERSON P 
    LEFT JOIN PERSONLINE PL 
    ON P.ID = PL.ID,
    (SELECT count(PL.PERSONLINEID) cnt FROM PERSON P LEFT JOIN PERSONLINE PL ON P.ID = PL.ID WHERE 
    P.ID = PL.ID) cnt
```

JOIN Table (Expected):

```
ID              COUNT_PERSONLINE            NAME
100             3                           John
101             2                           James
102             1                           Janet
```

JOIN Table (Actual):

```
ID              COUNT_PERSONLINE            NAME
100             6                           John
101             6                           James
102             6                           Janet
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your sample data, you don't even need the `Person` table -- because you seem to have redundant table in the two tables.  You should probably fix this, but:

```
select pl.id, pl.name, count(*)
from personline pl
group by pl.id, pl.name;
```

Your count is just counting all the rows from the `join` of the tables -- that would be all the rows.  A simple aggregation should suffice, even if you decide that the `join` is still necessary.

EDIT:

You have several choices with lots of columns in `persons`.  One method is to put them in the `group by`:

```
select pl.id, pl.name, p.col1, p.col2, count(*)
from persons p join
     personline pl
     on p.id = pl.id
group by pl.id, pl.name, p.col1, p.col2
```

Another method is to do the aggregation before the `join`:

```
select p.*, pl.cnt
from person p join
     (select pl.id, pl.name, count(*) as cnt
      from personline pl
      group by pl.id, pl.name
     ) pl
     on p.id = pl.id;
```

Or, a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*, (select count(*) from personline pl where p.id = pl.id)
from person;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added a sample. There are many columns in Person table which is not in PersonLine table that I need to display as Result table.